# ngnix to apache configure proxy settings

Tags: nginx, httpd, apache-2.4, proxypass

I've to migrate from ngnix web server to apache web server.

The ngnix configured as proxy server for 80 and 443

ngnix confuiguration as following :

```
 server {
     listen 443;
     server_name my_root_domain.com;
     root /etc/nginx/html;
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://my_root_domain.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
  }

server {
     listen 80;
     server_name my_root_domain.com;
     root /etc/nginx/html;
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://my_root_domain.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
     }
 }
```

What Apache httpd.conf configuration will be same as above  ?

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nginx config looks wrong, because virtual host looks like TLS (*HTTPS*) site without SSL directives. 443 port is used for HTTPS, not HTTP. You will need a SSL certificate and private key to create HTTPS site. You can get one for free from [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/).

You will need mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http and mod_ssl. Make sure that these lines are uncommented in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule mod_ssl.so
```

Virtual host config would look like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my_root_domain.com
   <Location />
      ProxyPassReverse / http://my_root_domain.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName my_root_domain.com
   SSLEngine on
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

   SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache/conf/ssl.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache/conf/ssl.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/apache/conf/sub.class1.server.ca.pem

   <Location />
      ProxyPassReverse / http://my_root_domain.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```